# Extracting a slice of data from a 3D data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, 2d, slice

I have a 3 dimensional dataset of size 150x220x250 many scalar values. I look it at it as a stack of 150 slices of dimensions 220x250. I want to extract one of these 150 slices of 220x250. I used this command to extract the slice

```
slice = mydata(20, :, :);
```

This resulted in slice being of dimensions 220 x 250 **x 1**. I want the slice to be of dimensions 220 x 250 only. Can you please show me what Matlab command will help me get the desired slice as I need it.

Comment: @OlegKomarov, Awesome! That worked! Is there by the way a one-line command that combines extraction and squeeze?

Comment: `squeeze(mydata(20,:,:))`

Comment: If you are going to do that many times for your 3D array, consider defining `mydata2 = permute([2 3 1]);`, and then you can do `slice = mydata2(:, :, 20);` without `permute` (trailing singleton dimensions don't count for Matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `squeeze()` function removes singleton dimensions from an array.

e.g.

```
mydata=ones(150,220,250);
size(mydata)

ans =

   150   220   250

slice = squeeze(mydata(20,:,:));
size(slice)

ans =

   220   250
```

Or, you can permute your array so that the dimension you are extracting the slice is in the last dimension of the array. Then, the squeeze function is not needed, because Matlab omits the singleton dimension if it is the last dimension of the array.

e.g.

```
mydata_reordered = permute(mydata,[2 3 1]);
size(mydata_reordered)

ans =

   220   250   150

slice2 = mydata_reordered(:,:,20);
size(slice2)

ans =

   220   250
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll mark this as answer if you also elaborate Luis Mendo's point with an example.

Comment: Just did, hope it helps!